# Smoke looks blurry even though resolution is set to a high value

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

As you can see, smoke looks very blurry.

I have tried everything people said on other forum, but since the way blender simulates smoke has recently changed, most of it isn't helpful.

[image: My absolute mess of a smoke]

This was with 200 resolutions division and 3 upres factor. Most tutorials I watched used these setting or slightly more or less, yet they got noticeably better results, whether in viewport or rendering.

I don't see what I can do to up the quality, the edges are fuzzy and the whole picture is overall blurry.

Any help would be appreciated

Edit : this is with denoising  :

[image]

better, but still nowhere close to the cool high definition renders

Comment: Try significantly increasing Max Steps in the Volumes render properties and/or decrease the 'Step Rate' for render and/or viewport.

Comment: I don't know what tutorials you are watching, but that looks pretty comparable to what I've experienced with ~200 resolution divisions. The upres factor will not improve the appearance as much as increasing the resolution value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Number of Divisions has nothing to do with "blurry" result. More divisions gives more details (volume grid is detailed). You can try to sharpen with ...

Default 32 Divisions
[image]

add Math node Multiply 100 into Density socket
[image]

add node Color Ramp
[image]

to get rid of lines change *Render Properties > Volumes >* **Step Rate** 0.1
[image]

(Step Rate - lower value means less "lines" in a volume.)

Play with ColorRamp to get more or less of volume ...
[image]

Comment: This worked like a charm ! Thanks, I didn't expect this !