# Smoke is very blurry

Tags: smoke-simulation, blur

I have a simple smoke simulation (90 divisions), however render/viewport looks very blurry today (but was better yesterday, and I wouldn't know what I changed).

Smoke Material is quite basic. I tried to apply steps from [Smoke looks blurry even though resolution is set to a high value](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200790/smoke-looks-blurry-even-though-resolution-is-set-to-a-high-value) but result is too artificial.
Any idea what I should tweak to get a better smoke render/viewport quality ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't know the dimensions of the objects in the screenshot, but to me this looks relatively normal for 90 divisions, since this is still quite low.

Comment: The cube has the default size of 2m. However can it be linked to the fact the density was set to 50 ? I can make it smaller ben then the smoke is too transparent.

Comment: I don't know, you said it was better yesterday. Was the density lower yesterday?  In the _Material Properties_ tab, what do you see under _Settings_ > _Volume_ > _Interpolation_? Is it "Linear" or "Cubic"? Cubic can help reduce smoke blockiness with lower division settings, but looks more blurred in my opinion so I prefer Linear.

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed already on Linear. I have tried with bigger object size and it looks less blurry now. Since yesterday I remember having played with Density mainly.

Comment: Well, in general you can say almost every value you're tweaking can result in major differences in appearance of the smoke. Okay, this might be exaggerated. But even seemingly simple things like _Resolution Division_ which at first sounds like it just brings more detail, can change the flow behavior a lot.

Comment: What I often do is to use File::Recover::Auto_Save to find a version that gets me back to what I liked, and possibly Save_As so I can compare settings to see where I went astray.

Comment: I'd say increasing the resolution of the smoke to at least double what it is now will definetely make it look less blurry and blobby. Adding some noise in the smoke settings might help too.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ticking the noise box? It adds lots of data on top of the original smoke